# In .net does a new thread get created for each System.Thread.Timer object in a process?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to execute methods at different intervals and was looking at using the Timer class to schedule this. However, I wanted to understand if the Timer spun up a new thread for each new schedule which could then potentially impact performance of the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For `System.Threading.Timer`:

Short-answer: 90% of the time: no. It uses the Thread Pool to get an existing thread (that isn't doing anything).

Long-answer: Possibly! If all threads in the pool are busy then a new thread will need to be created by the OS and added to the pool and then used by the Timer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method on **a thread pool thread** at specified intervals. This class cannot be inherited.

### For other timer types:

- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` triggers a new Win32 Window Message to be sent to the `Form` at a set interval. It does not use a dedicated thread nor a pool thread, instead it uses Win32's `SetTimer` function.
- `System.Timers.Timer` will also use a pool thread by default (just like `System.Threading.Timer`) but lets you perform thread synchronization. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

### A single-threaded alternative using coroutines:

I recommend you look at using `await Task.Delay` instead - as it won't cause a new thread to be used (remember that `Task`s are not Threads) - though if you do use `Task.Run` to run the coroutine in a pool thread then it may run on a new thread:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static async Task<Int32> Main( String[] args )
    {
        Task loop30 = this.Every30Seconds();
        Task loop20 = this.Every20Seconds();
        Taks loop10 = this.Every10Seconds();

        await Task.WhenAll( loop30, loop20, loop10 );

        return 0;
    }

    public static async Task Every30Seconds()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping!");

            await Task.Delay( 30 * 1000 );
        }
    }

    public static async Task Every20Seconds()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pong!");

            await Task.Delay( 20 * 1000 );
        }
    }

    public static async Task Every10Seconds()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pang!");

            await Task.Delay( 10 * 1000 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right when it's a timer from System.Threading namespace. But there are other 3 timers in the .Net. So, if you can write the complete answer it could be great.

Answer (score 2):

Dai's done a good job of answering the question regarding timers and threads.

I thought I'd give you an alternative way of writing your code. You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

EventLoopScheduler els = new EventLoopScheduler();

els.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

IObservable<string> pings = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), els).Select(x => "Ping!");
IObservable<string> pongs = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), els).Select(x => "Pong!");
IObservable<string> pangs = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), els).Select(x => "Pang!");

IObservable<string> query = Observable.Merge(els, pings, pongs, pangs);

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x} ({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})"));

Console.ReadLine();

subscription.Dispose();
els.Dispose();
```

The `EventLoopScheduler` creates a single, dedicated, re-usable thread that you can used until you call `.Dispose()` on it.

Both `Observable.Timer` and `Observable.Merge` allow you to specify that you want to use the `EventLoopScheduler` to ensure that the code is run on that thread.